# Can I play games on my laptop with HDMI output to a television

Tags: laptop, hdtv

I am getting a Dell XPS laptop as a Christmas present. From what I have been reading online it can play some modern PC games pretty well (3 GB Nvidia® GeForce®  GT 555M). I don't want to play games on a small laptop screen. Can I hook it up to my HD television and use it like a defacto gaming console?

I am guessing there might be some kind of problem with screen resolutions not matching up or something like that. Is there any extra hardware I need to buy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just send the output to JUST the HDTV, then you can use the TV's native resolution. So, if you have a 1080P television, it will send out to 1080P, assuming your graphics card supports it and you use a DVI or HDMI cable (will VGA output 1080p?)

Comment: I know my television supports 1080i because that is what my Xbox uses I am not sure if the GeForce does. I am not sure if a modern game like Skyrim for example can run at that resolution.

Comment: Modern games should run at whatever resolution you set it, as long as the computer can handle it (i.e. Gfx card)

Comment: You can also use both screens at once, and have different resolutions set for each screen.

Comment: @SaintWacko Only some games would support that with different resolutions, or different screens

Comment: @Luke Oh, I didn't mean playing the game on both screens at once. You play the game on the big screen and use the little one for Skype/TS/Vent or whatever. I'm just saying you don't have to set it to *just* HDTV.

Comment: @SaintWacko Right :) I used to do that in Windows

Comment: Yes, VGA supports 1080p, though you may have driver issues. I've had about 80% success getting the VGA to output the correct resolution to 1080p monitors. If the laptop has HDMI it should be used instead.